# ld: fatal: library -lm: not found in solaris 10

Tags: c++, g++, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to compile a object file in SOLARIS 10 ,

```
g++ -g -fPIC -Wall -fno-builtin -fhuge-objects -Wl,-Bdynamic,-lposix4,-laio,-ldl,-lthread,-Bstatic filename.o -L. -L /directory1 -L /directory2 -ldirectory1 -ldirectory2 -o filename

it is giving following error:
ld: fatal: library -lm: not found
ld: fatal: library -lc: not found
ld: fatal: library -lc: not found
```

Now I am just surprised that I have not even included -lm and -lc in g++ command line compilation , then why it is reporting error like that and when I am giving same compilation in SOLARIS 8 , its working.Can anyone please clarify that why it is behaving like that?

I used following command to make filename.o:

```
g++ -I/direcroty_containing_header_file -c filename.cpp -o filename.o -g -fPIC -Wall -fno-builtin -fhuge-objects
```

Comment: Try changing `-Wl,-Bdynamic,-lposix4,-laio,-ldl,-lthread,-Bstatic`  to `-Wl,-Bdynamic,-lposix4,-laio,-ldl,-lthread,-lm,-lc,-Bstatic` .

Comment: thanks for your comment,i tried to change like you suggested, its not working, same error.

Comment: Can you tell us the command line you used to create `filename.o` ?

Comment: Just edited Q, please check..

Answer (score 3):

Solaris 10 does not have libc.a nor libm.a.  Solaris 8 does.

You can not link to libc nor libm statically on Solaris 10.

Comment: you mean to say i should not use -Bstatic , but i have tried without that flag, I am getting same error....and also Q is , I am not using a option -lm in g++ , then why its reporting lm not found.

Comment: Is the exact link command logged or otherwise available?  Without that exact command, I can only guess - and most likely be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Libc and libm are standard C and math libraries, they are typically automatically linked to by g++ since they're so commonly used. Without knowing anything about your setup it's difficult to say why ld can't find them, likely the ones that exist are unused for some reason (different architecture, not in search path, etc).

Comment: I think ld find to try library based on LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable , i have tried that option also , its not working , on top of that i have try giving -L /lib option also , where libm.so and libc.so is present , it is also not working.

Comment: -Bstatic might be messing you up, it looks like libm.so and lib.so are dynamic libraries. Try removing the -Bstatic from your command.

Comment: Can you add more information about your project to your question? I made a test program on my Solaris box mirroring what you've showed me and I've got the same linker error, but removing -Bstatic fixed that.

Comment: Solaris 10 does not provide static versions of libc nor libm.